# Hartshorne Exercise II. 3.3 (c) for locally of finite type?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, schemes

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$Exercise II. 3.3 (c) in Hartshorne's *Algebraic geometry* is

> Show also if $f: X \to Y$ is of finite type, then for *every* affine subset $V = \Spec(B) \subset Y$, and for *every* open affine subset $U = \Spec A \subset f^{-1}(V)$, $A$ is a finitely generated $B$-algebra.

My proof is to cover $f^{-1}(V)$ by finitely many open affines $\Spec A_i$, such that each $A_i$ is a finitely generated $B$-algebra. Then we can cover $U$ by finitely many open affines $D(a), a \in A$, which are both standard opens with respect to $\Spec A$ and one of the $\Spec A_i$ (see [this lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IW)). Then each $D(a)$ is finitely generated over one of the $A_i$, and hence also finitely generated over $B$. Then [this property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291667/finite-covering-by-finitely-generated-b-algebras)  asserts that $A$ is indeed finitely generated over $B$.

However, I wonder if we really need $f$ to be of finite type, or if $f$ being locally of finite type is sufficient? Because we only need that we can cover $U$ by finitely many of the $D(a)$, which is certainly true in either case, because $U$ is quasi-compact. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, and in fact locally of finite type is *equivalent* to the statement that for all open affines $U\subset X$ and $V\subset Y$ with $f(U)\subset V$, the ring map $\mathcal{O}_Y(V)\to\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is of finite type. See for instance the proof at [Stacks 01T2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01T2).

Comment: Thank you for the reference!